# Does rejection of null hypothesis ($p < \alpha$) for one representative sample imply rejection in a different sample?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

I am new to hypothesis testing so forgive me if this has already been asked. Suppose that I've already decided on a null hypothesis with a significance level $\alpha = 0.05$, then obtained my representative sample, then computed the statistic of concern, and then computed a $p$-value that leads me to reject my null hypothesis.

1) Does it follow that I'll *reject the null hypothesis* again when I perform the experiment on another representative sample? 

I think not necessarily but I would like a more *mathematically* formal answer. But one practical consideration is that performing the experiment again may not be possible or may be costly, so that generalizing the result from one *representative* sample may seem like a good idea. 

One interpretation told to me, with $\alpha=0.05$, is that if I were to perform the experiment $100$ times with $100$ *representative samples*, then $5$ times, the statistic will fall in the rejection region, leading me to *reject the null hypothesis*.

2) Can I think of these $5$ times as obtaining $p$ values less than $\alpha$?

Thanks for any help or useful links.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want when you say 'mathematically formal'? I could stick symbols all over my answer but it would only render it less readable, not any more correct.

Answer (score 5):

> Does rejection of null hypothesis (p<α) for one representative sample imply rejection in a different sample?

Definitely not.

Consider a hypothesis test carried out at level $\alpha$. When $H_0$ is true, you reject a fraction of the time that is $\alpha$ (or for composite null, no more than $\alpha$).

So imagine $H_0$ is true and you reject. You then get a new sample at random from the population. The probability that the next sample would result in rejection would still only be $\alpha$.

Now consider a situation where the null is false, but where the *power* is 50%. Then the probability that the next sample will reject given the current sample rejected is a toss-up.

In particular, for two random samples taken independently from the same population, the probability of rejection for each is normally *independent* of a rejection in the other (leaving aside some potential issues with small populations, and so on).

> Can I think of these 5 times as obtaining p values less than α?

Yes, the test statistic falling into the rejection region corresponds to a p-value $\leq \alpha$